# ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS status after creating dask-fargate-stack on AWS CloudFormation

Tags: dask, distributed-computing, amazon-sagemaker, dask-distributed, distributed-training

I am following [this guide](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/machine-learning-on-distributed-dask-using-amazon-sagemaker-and-aws-fargate/) to be able to use dask distributed on my sagemaker instance, so I can train my big data regression model, but when I create the stack, I get the status of ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS.

How can I manually create the stack for dask distributed? I can't seem to find the steps, and I guess the amazon's template for dask does not work, or maybe it's something else.

I tried using coiled for dask distributed on Sagemaker, but when coiled asks me for my token, I paste the token and I get an error.

Answer (score 2):

There is a somewhat related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72549748/10693596), if you decide to go with Coiled or SaturnCloud, both provide customer support that might offer more specific guidance.

Comment: Thanks mate!, I will give it a try with SaturnCloud, coiled has not worked for me yet due to an issue on validating my token.

Comment: That sounds like a very basic issue (re: token validation), so I think if you contact them by email or Slack they might be able to resolve it quickly.